# Change 1Password App extension navigation bar title color

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, ios-app-extension, uber-api

I am trying to change the color of navigation bar title and status bar items in 1Password App extension. I am unable to find a way to do it.

Please the image below.
[image]

There must be a way to do it, Uber app is doing it. Please find the image below.
[image]

Can some one please suggest me a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before presenting 1Password screen set the appearance as follows.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:nil];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]}];
```

In completion block of 1Password reset your appearance to your app sepecific appearance.

Answer (score 0):

change navigationBar title color:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor grayColor]};
```

change status bar font color:
1.in the Info.plist add item: UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance NO
[image]

2.add the code in [viewController viewDidLoad]

> tip:if you need change all viewController status font color，you should add in [AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Comment: We dont have access to navigation bar of 1Password to change its titleTextAttributes, as it is an App extension.

Comment: @pavan The 1Password app extension title text attributes inherits from your own apps color scheme, you don't need to have access to 1Passwords app extention

Comment: In 8.3 we are seeing few issues with the navigation bar in the second screen of 1Password. Any how I found the fix for it. Thanks for the help guys.